# how to control stepper motor with tb6560 using arduino

Tags: arduino

**This is my code to control stepper motor with tb6560 using arduino. But when i give a input through serial monitor the motor goes to that angle and comes back again. I want the motor to stop at the given input angle.**
CODE:

```
// defines pins numbers

const int stepPin = 3;

const int dirPin  = 2;

const int enPin  = 4;

int arr[10] = {10, 90, 45, 30, 60, 120, 180, 240, 280, 420};

int currentAngle;
 int angle;


float stepPerAngle = 1.8; // full step = 1.8

int   numstep;



void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Sets the two pins as Outputs

  pinMode(stepPin, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(dirPin, OUTPUT);



  pinMode(enPin, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(enPin, LOW);

  digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);




}

void loop() {



  int n;
 
  angle = Serial.parseInt();
  //  for(int i = 0;i < 10;i++){
  //   angle = arr[i];
  if ( currentAngle == angle) {
    digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);
  }
  else if ( currentAngle != angle ) {



    if ( currentAngle < angle) {

      digitalWrite(dirPin, HIGH);

      n = angle - currentAngle;

      numstep = n / stepPerAngle;

    }

    if ( currentAngle > angle) {

      digitalWrite(dirPin, LOW);

      n = currentAngle - angle;

      if ( angle == 0) {

        n = currentAngle;

      }

      numstep = n / stepPerAngle;

    }

    Serial.print("Current Angle=");
    Serial.print(currentAngle);
    Serial.print("Angle=");
    Serial.print(angle);
    Serial.print("step=");
    Serial.println(n);




    for (int x = 0; x < numstep; x++) {

      digitalWrite(stepPin, HIGH);

      delayMicroseconds(1000);

      digitalWrite(stepPin, LOW);

      delayMicroseconds(1000);

    }
    currentAngle = angle;
  }
  




  delay(500);
}
```

I tried to change many things in the code but i just dont know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

You constantly read the serial instead of waiting for new data to arrive.
Serial.parseInt() return 0 when no data received and it is treated as a normal angle value of zero degree.
Use Serial.available() wich return byte number in serial queue, so Serial.parseInt() will not be used before a real angle is received.

replace :

```
angle = Serial.parseInt();
```

by

```
if (Serial.available() > 0) {
    angle = Serial.parseInt();
  } else return;
```

note: I noticed that stepPin is not declared in your piece of code